# How to model an possible empty array with Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have the current scenario.

```
type A = { b: string, c: number }

an object that I'll consume from an API , that will give me either

A[] || []
```

Currently, if I try to use it,

```
const apiData: A[] || []
const b = apiData[0].a // this I wanted it to error, but it doesn't.
```

How do I model in a way where this will error ?

Comment: `const b = apiData[0].a` definitely does error. Also you have a typo, its `A[] | []`, not `A[] || []`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest solution here is `Partial`:

```js
type A = { b: string, c: number }

type Obj = Partial<A[]>
declare var apiData: Obj;

const check = apiData[0] // A | undefined
```

OR you can use typeguard

```js
type A = { b: string, c: number }

type Obj = A[]
declare var apiData: Obj;

const isEmpty = <Elem,>(arg: Elem[]): arg is never[] => arg.length === 0

if (isEmpty(apiData)) {
  const x = apiData[0] // never
} else {
  const x = apiData[0] // A
}
```

Next type

```js
type Obj = A[] | never[]
```

does not work as you might expect because `never[]` extends `A[]`

```js
type IsAssignable = never[] extends A[] ? true : false // true
```

Also, you can use `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag